# How to implement this layout?

Tags: themes

probably a long shot, but here goes: for a WordPress portfolio site, I’m trying to build a project overview page with a layout similar to this: http://www.innauer-matt.com/

Each row of images is centered, with a margin of 60 px between the images. The container max-width is 1400 px, so that every time the viewport width is less than that, the images are rearranged.

If anyone could point me to a theme that works like this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your site doesn't have much dynamic components, and doesn't require many future content updates, you can easily achieve this with flex and a pinch of JS.

Check [this](https://medium.com/@js_tut/flexbox-the-animated-tutorial-8075cbe4c1b2) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would get any theme you like, find and install any Masonry or Isotope plugin (there is a lot), create a gallery using this plugin, create a page with this gallery and set this page as a home page. 
You just need to figure out which plugin fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much! Are there any plugins you’d recommend?

Comment: Honestly, haven't use any of them, but from their active installations they should be OK. Again, depends on what you need :)
[Photoswipe Masonry Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/photoswipe-masonry/)
[Image Photo Gallery Final Tiles Grid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/final-tiles-grid-gallery-lite/)
[Visual Portfolio](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-portfolio/#description)